# passport deserializeuser not being called

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

When I make a fetch request from my react frontend to login using passport.authenticate('./local), my passport.serializeUser is called but passport.deserializeUser is NOT (and req.user is not set).

I've read as many answers to this question on stackoverflow but to no avail. Here is my code below.

All this comes before my routes on the server.js:

```
//Express body parser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.json());

//Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {
    secure: false
  }
}));

// Passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport);

//Passport Middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Here is the passport config file:

```
module.exports = function(passport) {

    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
      function(username, password, done) {

        User.findOne({ username: username }, async function (err, user) {
          if (err) { return done(err); }
          if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
          const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
          if (!match) { return done(null, false); }
          return done(null, user);
        });
      }
    ));

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log('this gets called logged)
        done(null, user.id);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        console.log('this does NOT GET LOGGED');
        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
        });
    });
};
```

Here is the react fetch request for the login route:

```
fetch('http://localhost:5000/authentication/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state.formData),
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            mode: 'cors'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(resObject => {
                if (resObject.errors) {
                    console.log('errors')
                } else {
                    this.props.dispatch(handleLoginuser(resObject.user))
                    this.setState({
                        redirect: true                      
                    })
                }           
            });
```

Here is the fetch request for another random route that should be protected:

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/protectedroute', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            credentials: 'include'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(resObject => {
                if(resObject.loggedIn) {
                    this.setState({
                        loggedIn: true
                    })
                }
            });         
    }
```

Here are the login and protected routes:

```
app.post('/authentication/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
        res.json({errors: false, user: req.user})
    });

app.route('/protected')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            //req.user will be undefined!
            if (req.user) {
                return res.json({loggedIn: true})
            } else {
                return res.json({loggedIn: false})
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because of your post/login route on the back end.
Calling the passport.authenticate middleware does not complete the login process unless you use the boilerplate code from the official docs (which does not work with React)
You need to call req.login to complete the login process.  Check out this example

```
app.post('/authentication/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, theUser, failureDetails) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Something went wrong authenticating user' });
            return;
        }

        if (!theUser) {
            res.status(401).json(failureDetails);
            return;
        }

        // save user in session
        req.login(theUser, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'Session save went bad.' });
                return;
            }
            console.log('---123456789098765432345678---', req.user);
            res.status(200).json({{errors: false, user: theUser}});
        });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Comment: wow...just figured it out. In my case, I wasn't setting credentials: 'include' in the login post request.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up `withCredentials: true` while sending the post request worked for me.

```
axios.post(uri, {
  email: email,
  password: password
}, {
  withCredentials: true
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this for myself:

I had to change deserialize method to:

```
passport.deserializeUser(async function (id, done) {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id).exec();
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});
```

Including `.exec()` fixed it.

In the axios call, I had to include:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Then in my `app.js`:

```js
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
```